# The Human Menstrual Cycle

Tags: homework, reproduction

1) What happens in the ovary and in the bloodstream that brings about this change in the uterus?
2) Why does the level of FSH decrease and remain at a relatively low level during the luteal phase of the cycle?

---

For 1 I was thinking: So estrogen levels increase and the follicle matures which first cause menstruation and then the lining reforms?? 
For 2 I was thinking: the follicle has already ruptured by the luteal phase

Comment: I addressed this topic in [an answer to a related question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/21836/9268). Although it’s a different question, I think both of yours are answered in the background I provided in that answer. (P.S. You need to specify what you’re referring to by “this” change in the first question - probably either a proliferative or secretory endometrium, or maybe menstruation? Or if it corresponds to the title, do you mean the entire cycle - “these changes”?)

Comment: Please expand on he abbreviation FSH

Comment: This sounds quite a lot like a homework/exam question, so I added the relevant tag.