# How can the symptoms of ovulation (pms or pmdd) occur if one is menstrating?

Tags: menstrual-cycle

Even if your period is lasting overly long. Wouldn't starting to ovulate end menstrating?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can ovulation and menstruation occur simultaneously?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21818/can-ovulation-and-menstruation-occur-simultaneously)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources).  ——— Thank you for taking the  [tour], but please also go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 